# insert php variable into HTML form field from php function

Tags: php, forms, insert, passwords, field

I have written a php function which generates a random password based on a set of rules. I want to insert the $randomPassword variable into an HTML form field after the user clicks a 'Generate Random Password' button (without refreshing the page) which calls the php function. Once the random password is in the form field the user clicks the 'Submit' button to change the password in the database.

What is the best way of getting the php variable into the form field? I have done loads of searching but cannot come up with a workable solution.

Any tips on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

*** EDIT ***

Thanks for all the feedback below but I found a starting point today to work on, this is form:

```
                <form name="passwordform" action="" method="post">
                    <div>
                        <?php
                            if ( $error )
                                echo '<font color="red">'. $message . "<br></font>";
                           else
                               echo $message;
                        ?><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "password is required">
                        <div class="content">
                            <input class="input100" type="password" id="pass1" name="new_password" placeholder="New Password"</input>
                            <span class="focus-input100-1"></span>
                            <span class="focus-input100-2"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "password is required">
                        <div class="content">
                            <input class="input100" type="password" id="pass2" name="confirm_new_password" placeholder="Confirm New Password"</input>
                            <span class="focus-input100-1"></span>
                            <span class="focus-input100-2"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="first">
                        <div class="group1">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
                            <label id="showhide" class="label">Show Passwords</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script src="_js/showhide.js"></script><br>
                    <?php echo $passwordSyntaxMessage . "<br>";
                        if ($reCAPTCHAcheck)
                            echo '<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=' . $reCAPTCHAsiteKey . '></div><br>';
                    ?>
                    <input class="login100-form-btn" name="insert" type="button" value="Generate Random Password" onClick="randomPassword();" /><br>
                    <div style="float:left; padding-right: 0px">
                        <input class="form-button" style="width: 180px" name="insert" type="submit" value="Set Password" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right; padding-right: 0px">
                        <input class="form-button" style="width: 180px" name="insert" type="reset" value="Reset Form" />
                    </div>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript" >
                    function randomPassword() {
                        var pass = <?php echo generateRandomPassword();?>; 
                        passwordform.new_password.value = pass;
                        passwordform.confirm_new_password.value = pass;
                    }
                </script>
```

If I click on the "Generate Random Password" button, the 2 password fields remain blank. The php function generateRandomPassword() is in a file called functions.php and I know it works because I can echo the result in a browser.

If I replace the line:

```
var pass = <?php echo generateRandomPassword();?>;
```

with:

```
var pass = "testing 1 2 3";
```

Sure enough the phrase "testing 1 2 3" is inserted into the 2 password fields!

So where am I going wrong with calling the php function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Please remove if condition because you are not sending anything as query parameter, you are calling just filename action.php**

```
            <?php

                // Add codes your desired PHP function that generate password. I am adding some code that i got from somewhere.
                
                $alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
                $alpha_upper = strtoupper($alpha);
                $numeric = "0123456789";
                $special = "!@$#*%";

                // Concatinate all variables into one long string
                $chars = $alpha . $alpha_upper . $numeric . $special;

                // Select password length
                $length = 10;

                // Suffle the value of $chars
                $chars = str_shuffle($chars);

                // Return the length of your new $chars string
                $len = strlen($chars);

                // Create empty variable that will hold your new password
                $pw = '';

                // A simple 'for' statement that will select random characters for the lenth of your password
                for ($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
                    $pw .= substr($chars, rand(0, $len-1), 1); 

                // Store the finished password in a variable, that will shuffle the value created by the 'for' statement
                $pw = str_shuffle($pw);

                // show the password on screen
                echo $pw;

            ?>
```

**Now it will work.**

Comment: I got it working based on your suggestion. I moved my function to generate the password out of functions.php into it its own php file and it now works as it should. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Following Codes: This can be done using AJAX.

**index.html**

```
<form action="" method="">
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
    <button type="button" onclick="generate_password();">Generate</button>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
function generate_password()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("password").value = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "action.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

**action.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['generate_password']))
{
    // Add codes your desired PHP function that generate password. I am adding some code that i got from somewhere.
    
    $alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $alpha_upper = strtoupper($alpha);
    $numeric = "0123456789";
    $special = "!@$#*%";

    // Concatinate all variables into one long string
    $chars = $alpha . $alpha_upper . $numeric . $special;

    // Select password length
    $length = 10;

    // Suffle the value of $chars
    $chars = str_shuffle($chars);

    // Return the length of your new $chars string
    $len = strlen($chars);

    // Create empty variable that will hold your new password
    $pw = '';

    // A simple 'for' statement that will select random characters for the lenth of your password
    for ($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
        $pw .= substr($chars, rand(0, $len-1), 1); 

    // Store the finished password in a variable, that will shuffle the value created by the 'for' statement
    $pw = str_shuffle($pw);

    // show the password on screen
    echo $pw;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery AJAX also

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
   function generate_password(){
    $.ajax({
            method: "get",
            data: {generate_password: true},
            url: "action.php",
            success: function(data){
                $("#password").val(data)
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```